# RxSwift + canMoveRowAt

Tags: swift, uitableview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm using RxSwift (RxCocoa) to populate my tableView cells

```
viewModel.cellsDriver.drive(tableView.rx.items) { ... }
```

This way I have no access to tableView's dataSource's method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
```

But I need to specify which rows are movable for

```
tableView.rx.itemMoved
```

How can I restrict which rows should not be able to drag around? I would prefer avoid using RxDataSources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to do one of two things. Either pull in the RxDataSource Cocoapod and use one of the `TableViewSectionedDataSource` subclasses or make your own data source.

It's not hard to make a data source. Here's an example: https://github.com/dtartaglia/RxMultiCounter/blob/master/RxMultiCounter/RxExtensions/RxSimpleAnimatableDataSource.swift I used DifferenceKit in mine, but if you want to be super simple, you can just call `tableView.reloadData()` in your `func tableView(_:observedEvent)` method.

Here's an example:

```
//
//  RxTableViewMovableRowDataSource.swift
//
//  Created by Daniel Tartaglia on 12/19/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Daniel Tartaglia. MIT License.
//

import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa


class RxTableViewMovableRowDataSource<E, Cell: UITableViewCell>: NSObject, RxTableViewDataSourceType, UITableViewDataSource {

    init(identifier: String, configure: @escaping (Int, E, Cell) -> Void, canMoveRowAt: ((Int, E) -> Bool)? = nil) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.configure = configure
        self.canMoveRowAt = canMoveRowAt
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, observedEvent: Event<[E]>) {
        values = observedEvent.element ?? []
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return values.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell
        let row = indexPath.row
        configure(row, values[row], cell)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        let row = indexPath.row
        return canMoveRowAt?(row, values[row]) ?? true
    }

    let identifier: String
    let configure: (Int, E, Cell) -> Void
    let canMoveRowAt: ((Int, E) -> Bool)?
    var values: Element = []
}
```